# Why is borne a past participle of bear?

Tags: past-tense, past-participles, inflectional-morphology, germanic-languages

This is a question people seldom ask. In the English language, past participles are verbs that usually end with *-ed*. But *bear* is one exception. It has *bore* and *borne* as past participles, but not *beared*. Why do they even exist? That doesn't make any sense.

Update 1: I'm not familiar with Germanic languages in general, past tense forms, irregular verbs, or inflectional morphology.

Update 2: *Borne* is the trickiest verb form I have heard from in the English language so far.

Comment: I'm curious what your mother tongue is; most natural languages have at least a few irregularly inflected words, and learning irregular verbs and nouns is a common challenge when learning any new language, not just English.

Comment: See [1](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/60987), [2](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/221913), [3](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/90651), [4](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/4399), [5](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/35030), [6](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/223556), [7](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/48078), [8](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/384205), [9](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/106634), [10](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/342033), [11](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/221914), [12](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/68388).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word *bear* started out as a perfectly normal [strong class 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germanic_strong_verb#Classes_1_to_6) verb in Old English. Because of this, it has a Germanic root which is the origin of the past forms *bore,* *born,* and *borne.* *Bear* is currently classified as an irregular verb because people normally do not add *-ed* to the end of the word when they use a specific past form.

Comment: You might want to take a look at: lie, lay, lain AND lay, laid, laid.

Answer (score 9):

To be clear, it is not standard to use "bore "as the past participle of *bear.* *Bear* has *borne* as a past participle, and possibly also *born,* if you consider the "be born" construction to function in present-day English as a passive form of "bear." (To me, the connection between "be born" and "bear" seems more a matter of history, not so much an active connection.)

Many past participles end in *-en,* *-n* or *-ne.* Past participles formed with a suffix containing /n/ are considered irregular today, but they come from the historical conjugation of "strong" verbs, which are a large and important category of Germanic verbs.

Most relevantly, the past participles of *tear, wear, swear* are *torn, worn, sworn.* Some other past participles not ending in *-ed* are *done, gone, eaten, broken.* There are many more examples. So "borne" is not very exceptional in not using *-ed.* The fact that it takes the spelling *-ne* rather than *-n* (if we leave out the "be born" construction) is more surprising.

All past participle forms, whether formed regularly with *-ed* or irregularly in some other way, can be ambiguous with adjectives. Many adjectives have the form of past participles: for example, *frozen, excited, dejected, disappointed.*

Answer (score 1):

“Bear” has two past participles, depending on the meaning you want. We use “borne” for most meanings, but “born” for passive constructions referring to birth:

[borne:](https://www.etymonline.com/word/borne)

> "carried, sustained, endured," past tense and participle of bear (v.) in all senses not related to birth. 
>   Distinction between born and borne (q.v.) is 17c.

(Etymonline)

Comment: The quote reads as though "I have born my son" is correct. A little more detail is required here, I think.

Comment: @AndrewLeach - “born” ***for passive constructions*** referring to birth. Your example in not a passive construction. “My son was born.....”

Comment: I stand by my comment. More detail is required in the answer.

Comment: @AndrewLeach - sorry, more details about what?

Comment: By now, _(be) born_ is a deponent verb with a distant relation to the terms _bear children_ and _child-bearing_. It isn't really a passive, except in form, and it doesn't take an agent _by_-phrase, as _borne_ does (_This device is borne by the Death's-Head Battalion_.)

Comment: @AndrewLeach: As the answer here says, "have borne" is not passive. This answer could cite the example in the [AHD's usage note](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=bear), which uses practically the same wording to describe the distribution of the two written forms:

Comment: "Thanks to the vagaries of English spelling, bear has two past participles: born and borne. Traditionally, born is used only in passive constructions referring to birth: I was born in Chicago. For all other uses, including active constructions referring to birth, borne is the standard form: She has borne both her children at home. I have borne his insolence with the patience of a saint."

Comment: This question isn't even about whether or not the word *borne* relates to birth. All it's about is why the word itself is a past participle of *bear*, as well as why it even exists.